# How to fix FORTRAN IV error: "a dummy argument name is invalid in this context"

Tags: fortran, intel-fortran

I need to run an old FORTRAN IV code I was given (which is supposed to run just fine). I downloaded a trial version of Intel compiler and tried to compile the source file I was given with the command:

```
ifort  -f66 abel.for -o mycode
```

where abel.for is the name of the source file. I got a bunch of warnings and errors. I wanted to ask about the first error I was given:

```
A dummy argument name is invalid in this context [DINT]
```

The compiler error is indicating the line:

```
EXTERNAL DINT
```

in the next subroutine:

```
      SUBROUTINE ABEL4(IN,X,Y,DINT,YCALC)                               AAOK0354
      IMPLICIT REAL*8(A-H,O-Z)                                          AAOK0355
      EXTERNAL DINT                                                     AAOK0356
      DIMENSION X(1),Y(1),YCALC(1)                                      AAOK0357
      COMMON /PI/ PI                                                    AAOK0358
      COMMON /R/ R                                                      AAOK0359
      COMMON /IK/ IK                                                    AAOK0360
      COMMON /SPLIN/ XN(100),FN(100),GN(100),B(251),D(251),N            AAOK0361
      DO 50 L=1,IN                                                      AAOK0362
      R=X(L)                                                            AAOK0363
      IK=L                                                              AAOK0364
      IF(R.EQ.0.D0) R=1.D-6                                             AAOK0365
      YCALC(L)=0.D0                                                     AAOK0366
      IF(R.EQ.X(IN)) R=R-1.D-6                                          AAOK0367
      RE=1.D-6                                                          AAOK0368
      LEV=1                                                             AAOK0369
      UL=1.D0                                                           AAOK0370
      WL=R+1.D-6                                                        AAOK0371
      CALL DINTEG(YC,DINT,WL,UL,1.D-12,RE,LEV,ERR,IFL)                  AAOK0372
      YCALC(L)=-(-Y(L)/(1.D0-R*R)**.5D0+YC)/PI                          AAOK0373
50    CONTINUE                                                          AAOK0374
      RETURN                                                            AAOK0375
      END
```

I must also point out that the main program first lines are:

```
      BLOCK DATA                                                        AAOK0028
        COMMON /WR/ IR,IW                                               AAOK0029
        DATA IR/5/,IW/6/                                                AAOK0030
      END                                                               AAOK0031
C                                                                       AAOK0032
C                 M  A  I  N      P  R  O  G  R  A  M                   AAOK0033
C                                                                       AAOK0034
C                                                                       AAOK0035
C COMMON AREAS:                                                         AAOK0036
C     /WR/ - I/O CHANNNELS. SEE BLOCK DATA.                             AAOK0037
C     /PI/ - PI=3.14......                                              AAOK0038
C     /R/  - R IS THE POSITION OF THE POINT CURRENTLY INVERTED.         AAOK0039
C     /SPLIN/ - X,Y ARE INPUT ARGUMENTS AND DATA,N -NO. OF KNOTS,       AAOK0040
C               XN,FN,GN -KNOTS,SPLINE VALUE AND ITS FIRST DERIVATIVE   AAOK0041
C                         AT KNOTS.                                     AAOK0042
C                                                                       AAOK0043
      IMPLICIT REAL*8 (A-H,O-Z)                                         AAOK0044
      DIMENSION A(100),B(100),YCALC(251),YREAL(251),                    AAOK0045
     *          C(100),D(100),XD(500),YD(500),WD(500),W(8006),          AAOK0046
     *          DN(500),THETA(500),RD(500)                              AAOK0047
      EXTERNAL DINT,GINT                                                AAOK0048
      COMMON /WR/ IR,IW                                                 AAOK0049
      COMMON /PI/ PI                                                    AAOK0050
      COMMON /R/ R                                                      AAOK0051
      COMMON /SPLIN/ XN(100),FN(100),GN(100),X(251),Y(251),N            AAOK0052
      DATA WD/500*1.D0/                                                 AAOK0053
      PI=4.D0*DATAN(1.D0)                                               AAOK0054
```

and also contain a statement of:

```
EXTERNAL DINT
```

in line AAOK0048, and also there is a definition of a function DINT in the program:

```
C                                                                       AAOK0377
C INTEGRAND  FOR INVERSION FORMULA 4                                    AAOK0378
C                                                                       AAOK0379
      DOUBLE PRECISION FUNCTION DINT(T)                                 AAOK0380
      IMPLICIT REAL*8 (A-H,O-Z)                                         AAOK0381
      COMMON /IK/ IK                                                    AAOK0382
      COMMON /SPLIN/ XN(100),FN(100),GN(100),X(251),Y(251),N            AAOK0383
      U=SPLVAL(-1,N,XN,FN,GN,T)                                         AAOK0384
      V=X(IK)                                                           AAOK0385
      S=SPLVAL(-1,N,XN,FN,GN,V)                                         AAOK0386
      DINT=(U-S)*T/(T*T-V*V)**1.5D0                                     AAOK0387
      RETURN                                                            AAOK0388
      END                                                               AAOK0389
```

I would appreciate if someone can help in this maze, and tell me how to fix this error, since I don't have much knowledge of FORTRAN let alone FORTRAN IV.

Comment: Can't see anything incorrect (as opposed to wrong) myself, but I only really know f77 onwards. Certainly gfortran 4.9.2 under cygwin is happy. Are you REALLY sure this is fortran IV? What I've seen so far looks like (very old school) fortran 77.

Comment: The program summary document of this code states that the programming language is: FORTRAN IV G

Comment: the `EXTERNAL` statement says `DINT` is a function.  It should not be needed in the subroutine `ABEL4` (But should not throw that error either).  What happens if you don't use the `-f66` flag?

Comment: Is it safe to just delete this line?

Comment: I believe it is safe to delete, the reason being that it is never directly used in `ABEL4`, but only "passed through" as an argument to `DINTEG`.